# Can SharePoint-Online index on prem file Shares?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm looking at Cloud Hybrid architecture.  My understanding is it will only index metadata from on-prem SharePoint installations.  I can't find if you can index other content sources.

Thanks.

Comment: federated search on on-prem sharepoint can index external sources, i don't know if if the hybrid architecture will pass those indexes to the online server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, SharePoint Online cannot index other content sources. In order to index non-SharePoint Online content sources, you must deploy the Cloud Search Service with an on-prem SharePoint 2013 or higher farm.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: ups, autocorrector screwed me.

While you can index from external sources on SP-on-prem, you  cannot do it on SP-Online

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can when configured as Office Cloud Hybrid search. See [https://docs.microsoft.com/](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hybrid/plan-cloud-hybrid-search-for-sharepoint) and [https://docs.microsoft.com/](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hybrid/configure-cloud-hybrid-searchroadmap) for details of capabilities and how to configure the system.